# access Oracle sql server remotely

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jboss

Ok, so I started working on my machine locally but I still need to access the database on the remote server. I was using this...

> DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
>
> conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dukeorrac01:1521:ORDB1","nrsc","nrsc");

But that doesn't seem to be accessing a remote server. I assume I need some sort of IP address in there somewhere. I realize I should use a datasource but I didn't set all this up and I don't have time to learn how to implement that (will do that after this project).

How do I access that remotely?

P.S. I'm using jboss as my locally running server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection string `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@dukeorrac01:1521:ORDB1","nrsc","nrsc"` **dukeorrac01** refers to the `host` where your DB is. Replace that with whatever host you want to connect to (assuming all others parts of the connection string stay the same).

Here is the syntax for oracle connection string

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID`

Comment: Oh, so that should work then? Is it possible that the server is simply not allowing my new computer to connect to it? (I'm getting exhausted resultsets so I'm not sure if it's a connection issue or what)